# When actually Amazon S3 triggers Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, awss3transfermanager

I have a very big file (estimated 50MB). I uploaded this file to an S3 directory which then triggers a Lambda function. I am using TransferManager to do the S3 upload.

I read the AWS document about Lambda and S3, it says the Lambda function is triggered when a file is created in S3, but I am still wondering if the created file means a file is uploaded completely.

My question: because of the large size of the file, there's a tiny delay of upload, so that is the Lambda function triggered before or after the file is uploaded completely? For example: during uploading a large file, the network is shut down, the file may be broken, so will the Lambda function still be triggered?

Comment: I think the bytes stream will be stored in a buffer and write it as a file, so the file will be created at a certain time. If an error occurs, then the writing process is not finished and the broken part cannot be a file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While very large is a relative term, S3 is used to handle much larger files than that, so AWS thought of that. Lambda Events will be triggered **after** the file has been created completely.

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html?shortFooter=true) describes this in more detail.

While not explicitly mentioned the documentation says that:

> Amazon S3 invokes your function asynchronously with an event that
>   contains **details about the object**. The following example shows an
>   event that Amazon S3 sent when a deployment package was uploaded to
>   Amazon S3.

(Emphasis mine)

Since it includes details about the object including its **size**, the object will have been uploaded completely, otherwise that wouldn't be known - here's a sample event that includes the size:

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.1",
      "eventSource": "aws:s3",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-2",
      "eventTime": "2019-09-03T19:37:27.192Z",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "AWS:AIDAINPONIXQXHT3IKHL2"
      },
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "205.255.255.255"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-request-id": "D82B88E5F771F645",
        "x-amz-id-2": "vlR7PnpV2Ce81l0PRw6jlUpck7Jo5ZsQjryTjKlc5aLWGVHPZLj5NeC6qMa0emYBDXOo6QBU0Wo="
      },
      "s3": {
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "configurationId": "828aa6fc-f7b5-4305-8584-487c791949c1",
        "bucket": {
          "name": "lambda-artifacts-deafc19498e3f2df",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "A3I5XTEXAMAI3E"
          },
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::lambda-artifacts-deafc19498e3f2df"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "b21b84d653bb07b05b1e6b33684dc11b",
          "size": 1305107,
          "eTag": "b21b84d653bb07b05b1e6b33684dc11b",
          "sequencer": "0C0F6F405D6ED209E1"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Agreed. Objects in Amazon S3 either exist, or don't exist. There is no concept of a "partial object". The object only exists after the upload successfully completes.

Comment: You could argue, that during multi-part uploads the object partially exists, but since you can't see it via the "standard"-APIs (GetObject) I think your statement is fair.

Comment: In the past, I did see a broken file uploaded in S3 because of network issue, it created a file in S3 but its size is zero or very small like 5KB 10KB (the real size is 50MB). At that time, I didn't use lambda functions so that I cannot verify if lambda is still triggered. If anyone has any experience about this, please share. Otherwise, this answer is the best.